# How to create a new separate buffer list in vim?

Tags: vim

There are some occasions that I wanted to open several files to be references and didn't want them to mess up my current buffer list. I have tried `:new`, `sp`, `vs`, and `:tabnew`, however, the new opened files are always kept in my current buffer list. Are there a way to create a brand new buffer list in order to keep these opened files separately? So, I could close these files entirely, whenever I didn't need to see them anymore, by using `1,100bd`. I have been googling it but still no luck.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific buffer to be not listed in the buffer list? If so you are probably looking for [`:setlocal nobuflisted`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#unlisted-buffer) option.

Comment: Your use of the word "buffer" is wrong. Each file is put into its own buffer and each buffer is added to the buffer list. Do you want multiple buffer lists or… something else?

Comment: Thanks @ryuichiro, I will take a look at it.

Comment: @romainl Oh, I just realized that. I actually need a separate buffer list. I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this plugin: [vim-ctrlspace](https://github.com/szw/vim-ctrlspace).

From  README.md of mentioned plugin:

> The answer are tabs – a secret weapon of Vim-CtrlSpace. Each tab holds
>   a separate list of buffers. And this is something very different when
>   compared to plain Vim. Tabs powered by the plugin can be seen as piles
>   of documents on the desk.
>
> With tabs you can, for example:
>
> - group related buffers
> - extract to other tabs
> - name them accordingly
> - move or copy them
>
> Tabs usage in Vim-CtrlSpace is quite more extensive than in Vim. This
>   is because they serve mainly as independent buffer lists, so you are
>   likely to have plenty of them. Tabs can be accessed and managed within
>   Tab List.
>
> All your buffers, tabs, and tab layouts can be persisted as a
>   workspace. It's like taking a picture of your desk with an instant
>   camera. You can save multiple workspaces per project with Workspace
>   List.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the argument list. See :help :args and surrounding sections. If all your reference files (and only those) are in your arg list, you could `:argdo bd` to get rid of them all. There are local arg lists too, if you are already using the global list.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** Using the plugin is almost certainly a more robust solution as I made this myself and I'm relatively new to vim. But this is at least a good exercise in the uses of quickfix lists.

**My Answer:**
You could use quickfix error lists as file lists. see `:help quickfix` for full documentation. Here is my work flow for when I want to go through all the files that differ from master (using git).

1. `vim` to open vim in the directory you are working on.
2. `new` to open a new buffer
3. `read ! git diff --name-only master` to paste the output of my bash command into the new buffer. You can run any command or manually enter a file list here. You may want to clean it a little by removing any blank lines.
4. `w! /tmp/quickfix.txt` to create a file name we can use later.
5. `set errorformat+=%f` to change the errorformat to accept vanilla lists of file paths. see `:help errorformat` for more details on that.
6. `cfile /tmp/quickfix.txt` to read the list of files and create a quickfix "error" list using the new errorformat.
7. `set errorformat-="%f"` (optional) this removes the added errorformat to make sure you're not messing with any other use of `errorformat`, like for a `vimgrep`.

Now you can use quickfix options to move between files. `:copen` to open an interactive list and `:cnext`/`:cprevious` to cycle them. You can also have multiple lists at once. I use `:colder` to go back to previous lists. You should be familiar with this if you use any `grep` commands in vim.

These are just the manual steps. You can make a function that does all this in one go or any part that you need. Here's what I'm using.

```
function! LoadQuickfixFileList(filename)
    set errorformat+=%f
    execute "cfile ".a:filename
    set errorformat-=%f
endfunction

function! WriteBufferToQuickFixFileList(filename)
    call writefile(getbufline(bufnr(bufname("%")), 0, "$"), a:filename)
endfunction

function! GitDiffNameOnlyMaster()
    execute "new"
    execute "read ! git diff --name-only master"
    execute "normal! ggdd"
    call WriteBufferToQuickFixFileList("/tmp/quickfix.txt")
    call LoadQuickfixFileList("/tmp/quickfix.txt")
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <leader>cgd :call GitDiffNameOnlyMaster()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>cw :call WriteBufferToQuickFixFileList("/tmp/quickfix.txt")<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>cf :call LoadQuickfixFileList("/tmp/quickfix.txt")<CR>
```

`<leader>cgd` does the whole thing for `git diff --name-only master`. If I make a list of files in a new buffer myself, I can use `<leader>cw` to write it to `/tmp/quickfix.txt`. Once I've done that or if I create a `/tmp/quickfix.txt` file myself in another way I use `<leader>cf` to load that file.